# Home (panic) button key bind

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, chromium

I was assigned to implement a panic/emergency button (key bind) that redirects the browser to homepage - I am not certain whether I shall use any chrome plugin - for instance a "Panic button" (that on the other side has couple of useless functions such as page reloading etc.) or a linux (Debian) script  that would restart the browser. The actual home button in browser is not a solution since the aim of my assignment is to create a browser based thin client.

I will be more than happy to hear your opinions, advices and comments